# Xen Server Cluster

Tags: xen

I have upwards of 30 Dell GX2xx models doing nothing. I've decided on using them to build a cluster, but I am lost as far as getting started. I've used ClusterKnoppix, and even straight OpenMosix in the past, but those projects are, very sadly, dead now.

I've checked out Xen, to an extent. I don't know if Xen is the solution I need. I'd like to have the ability to spin up a few VMs (when I need) in a server pool, with the VMs having the ability to run just off of resources in the pool, leaving me without the care of which node they run on.

I need some insight here... Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xen is not itself going to manage the whole cluster. 
It will act on every single machine to instantiate/manage/delete the VMs.
You can have a look at [Eucalyptus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_%28computing%29) if you want to build that kind of private cloud solution with open-source software.

I would also recommend that you use [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) that tends to be the successor of Eucalyptus.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out XCP, I find that it's really easy to start up a virtual cluster with this software.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at such projects as OpenAIS, Corosync, DRBD and Pacemaker? They are all apart of the Linux High Availability project (http://www.linux-ha.org). They offer many different configuration options for numerous types of servers (IE. MySQL, Apache, Xen, etc.).

They have custom scripts (LSB and OCF) that are ran in place of your standard init scripts and assume the roles of these init scripts. I have included a detailed guide for setting up a Xen HA cluster on OpenSuse 11.1 below for your reference. The configuration of the Linux HA components should be the same from distro to distro, except that the package names to be installed will vary, as well as the location of the specific configuration files. The command line tools should be the same as well as functionality. Hope this helps.

http://www.howtoforge.com/installation-and-setup-guide-for-drbd-openais-pacemaker-xen-on-opensuse-11.1